# China's Prosperity

Tags: production-function, political-economy, development

This is my first time doing this but with respects to economic prosperity. What are some of the tools/strategies that Chinese leader such as  Deng Xiaoping would have used to stimulate and enhance China's economy that could be used to do the same for small developing countries such as those in the Caribbean?

Comment: I am not sure this is a good question because china's economy has vastly different scale from a Caribbean country. It's like asking how a neighborhood restaurant can develop its business by learning from Shell Oil.  You may be better off asking what lessons can be learned from development in successful island economies like Singapore.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are right.  Singapore is a perfect example. Do you have any lessons?

Comment: Yes as a matter of fact. Could you edit your question to remove the reference to China? I will respond

Comment: @tohster see here http://economics.stackexchange.com/q/3387/2960